# Restoring data in a cluster with different number of nodes in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

If I need to restore snapshots from one cluster with(4 nodes) to another cluster with(3 nodes).
How will we do that,as per documentation?
Data of 1st node should be restored on the 1st node of the other cluster.
Similarly for 2 more nodes we can do.
What will we do with the data of the remaining one node of 1st cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Data is snapshotted/restored per-tablet. The new cluster will distribute the tablets on fewer nodes in your case and each node will have more tablets. You just have to go over all the nodes and restore each tablet according to how they were distributed when you imported the snapshot file. Doesn't matter the number of nodes.

More details at: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/manage/backup-restore/snapshot-ysql/